# Conditional expression that returns -1 or 1 randomly

Tags: java, expression, conditional-statements

Is there any way in Java to write conditional expression that returns -1 or 1 randomly?

Comment: Like, `return random.nextBoolean() ? +1 : -1`?

Comment: A "conditional expression" or a "function"?  Conditional expressions resolve to boolean values, not integer values.

Comment: That is nonsense. If you want a random result a condition is unneccesary. Maybe the word conditional is superfluous in your question?

Answer (score 0):

This Java code returns -1 or 1 randomly;

```
return random.nextBoolean() ? -1 : +1
```

Answer (score 0):

A function is what you need it seems,

```
public int getRandom()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextBoolean() ? +1 : -1;
}
```

**Note**: don't forget the import `java.util.Random;`

Hope that helps.

Comment: You should not create a new random number generation each time the function is called! In the best case, it is wasteful. In the worst case, the method is called many times in the same millisecond, resulting in all those numbers being the same, because all those random number generators are initialized with the same seed.

Comment: @tobias_k : thanks for pointing it out, looks like the best way is to use `Math.random()`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved it.

```
(int)(Math.random() * 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1.
```

Thanks guys anyway!

Comment: How about `Math.random() > 0.5 ? +1 : -1`? Might be easier to understand.